# Writing more text inside paragraph causes images to move back using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I feel like I'm missing something pretty obvious here, but essentially I'm trying to do a footer that 2 columns and 2 rows.

Each column will have an icon (32x32) and 2 lines of text by its side.

My problem is, if I use `justify-items: center`, the items will be centered inside each column, however, if I add more text in my paragraph, the text will expand both ways, sending the image that's on its left backwards (increasing the size of the parent div).

This means if I have different text sizes in those 2 lines, the footer items won't be aligned with each other.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #ecf3f6;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.footer-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  justify-items: center;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
}

.footer {
  margin-top: auto;
  background-color: #2ea2bf;
}

.footer-description {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.footer-item {}

footer p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="footer-wrapper">
      <div class="footer-item">
        <img class="footer-icons" src="img/localizacao.png">
        <p>
          <span class="footer-description">Morada</span> Congeriem arce homini.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-item">
        <img class="footer-icons" src="img/telefone.png">
        <p>
          <span class="footer-description">Telefone</span> +351 211 149 501
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-item">
        <img class="footer-icons" src="img/email.png">
        <p>
          <span class="footer-description">E-Mail</span> support@support.com
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-item">
        <img class="footer-icons" src="img/localizacao.png">
        <p>
          <span class="footer-description">Morada</span> Congeriem arce homini.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>
```

### Image of desired layout

[image: Footer]

Comment: can you add a drawing of the wanted layout? I guess for what you trying to do, css-grid will be the smarter solution.

Comment: @tacoshy I've added a simple layout of what I'm trying to do to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed most of the classes to simplify it. Of course you can add them again.

I changed the grid to a width of `min-content` as well as the card width to `min-content`. However this causes an unwanted wrap behavior which is fixed with `white-space: nowrap;`

that way, every element will only be as large as the content. If you want an intended linebreak, you have to use `<br>`.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #ecf3f6;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

footer {
  margin-top: auto;
  background-color: #2ea2bf;
}

.footer-wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  width: min-content;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content min-content;
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.footer-wrapper div p span {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.footer-wrapper div {}

.footer-wrapper div p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="footer-wrapper">
    <div>
      <img class="footer-icons" src="img/localizacao.png">
      <p>
        <span>Morada</span> Congeriem arce homini.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="footer-icons" src="img/telefone.png">
      <p>
        <span>Telefone</span> +351 211 149 501
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="footer-icons" src="img/email.png">
      <p>
        <span>E-Mail</span> support@support.com
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="footer-icons" src="img/localizacao.png">
      <p>
        <span>Morada</span> Congeriem arce homini.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this not only works, but it's also much cleaner code!